# Update JobInfo.Builder when Use JobService

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-jobscheduler

Is possible to update JobInfo.builder when use JobService?I need to update interval,so the task will be executed when meet the time (You know when use setInterval and setMinimumLatency,the service will be crashed). In previous i use AlarmManager as task scheduler (API < 19), and expect the same behaviour when use it. Thank you.